# Не стираются все ключи в LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Нужно, чтобы стирались все два ключа при работе цикла

```
localStorage.setItem('2', 'lalala');
localStorage.setItem('3', 'lalala');

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    if (localStorage.key(i) > 1) {
        alert(localStorage.key(i)); // показывается два ключа
        localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i)); // удаляется не два, а один
    }
}
```

Comment: где-то пропущена закрывающая скобка `}`?

Comment: Исправил, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно очистить так:

```
localStorage.clear()
```

Comment: так уберутся вообще все ключи, а судя по условию в коде он хочет только те которые больше 1

Comment: @Grundy, хм.. А я заголовок вопроса читал...

Comment: Ага, но судя по самому вопросу похоже не совсем так.

Comment: @Grundy, наверное. Но тогда ему уже ответили, а при поиске и это может пригодиться.

Answer (score 1):

Код отрабатывает правильно. Вы добавили ключи "2" и "3" а длина localStorage = 2, так там всего 2 поля. Поэтому цикл будет идти до 2, а не до 3 и не дойдет до ключа 3.

Comment: Не понял. У меня всего два ключа, да. Длинна равна количеству ключей. Цикл обходит все элементы > 1 (используем alert и это видно). Но при удалении, почему то удаляет не все.

Comment: Думаю Grundy прав, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема сродни проблеме с функцией `splice`.

После удаления элемента, все остальные сдвинулись, и пропускается один элемент, так как счетчик все равно увеличился.

Для избежания этого можно обходить коллекцию с конца

```
localStorage.setItem('2', 'lalala');
localStorage.setItem('3', 'lalala');

for (var i = localStorage.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (localStorage.key(i) > 1) {
    console.log(localStorage.key(i)) //показывается два ключа
    localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(i)) //удаляется не два, а один
  }
}
```

Либо сначала выбрать все нужные ключи, и лишь затем пройтись по ним и удалить

```
localStorage.setItem('2', 'lalala');
localStorage.setItem('3', 'lalala');
Object.keys(localStorage).filter(key=>key>1).forEach(key=>localStorage.removeItem(key))
```

Кроме того стоит обратить внимание, что ключи и значения в *localStorage* - всегда только строки. Поэтому если ожидаются переменные какого-то другого типа - лучше привести к нему явно, во избежание неожиданного поведения.

Comment: `localStorage` это объект, а не массив. Индексы у него не сдвигаются.

Comment: @Arnial, вот только речь шла о ключах. _localStorage.key(i)_ здесь выбирается **ключ** по индексу, после удаления элемента, ключи сдвинулись.

Comment: @Arnial, если же рассматривать localStorage как объект, у него вообще нет индексов. Ну и строго говоря - это array-like объект, а не просто объект, поэтому поведение вполне может быть переопределено как угодно